# C++ Classes: errors with identifiers

Tags: c++, class

I've a project in C++ with 2 classes.

**MAIN.CPP:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int startHealth = 100, startArmor = 50, startEnemyHealth = 70, startWeapon = 1;

Player *Mick = new Player(startHealth, startArmor, startWeapon);
Enemy *Mon = new Enemy(startEnemyHealth);

cout << "START!" << endl;
cout << Mick->Health << " : " << Mick->Armor << endl;

cout << "ENEMY ATTACKS!" << endl;
Mon->Attack(Mick);

cout << "DAMAGE TAKEN!" << endl;
cout << Mick->Health << " : " << Mick->Armor << endl;

cout << "YOU ATTACK!" << endl;
Mick->Attack(Mon);

cout << "ENEMY'S HEALTH!" << endl;
cout << Mon->Health << endl;

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

**PLAYER.H**

```
#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"

class Player
{
public:
int Health, Armor;
int Weapon;

public:
Player(const int _startHealth, const int _startArmor, const int         _startWeapon);
~Player();
void Attack(Enemy *_attackedEnemy);
};
```

**ENEMY.H**

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"

class Enemy
{
public:
float Speed;
int Damage;
int Health;

public:
Enemy(const int _startEnemyHealth);
~Enemy();
void Attack(Player *_attackedPlayer);
void Refresh(Enemy *_enemyToRefresh);
};
```

The errors that I get are these ones:

[image]

Meanwhile, these are the errors that CodeBlocks gives me:

[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: you must forward declare the class, in player.h and enemy.h, as both includes each other but they wont be able to find the complete class definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When can I use a forward declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Player` class refers to your `Enemy` class, which also refers to your `Player` class:

```
class Enemy
{
    void Attack(Player *_attackedPlayer);
}
class Player
{
    void Attack(Enemy *_attackedEnemy);
}
```

What you need is **forward declaration**, to inform the compiler that a particular class exists, without telling it any information about this class.

Here you can add the following line in the file `Enemy.h`, before the definition of the `Enemy` class:

```
class Player;
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) to see what you can or cannot do with forward declarations.

### Why you need it here, even with the relevant `#include` directives

An `#include` directive is basically an instruction for the preprocessor that tells it to replace the directive by the included file. The `#pragma once` directive ensures that the file won't be included more than once for each translation unit.

In Main.cpp, here's what is going on:

- `#include "Player.h"`: the file `Player.h` is included.
- The first line of `Player.h` is `#include "Enemy.h"`: the file `Enemy.h` is included.
- The first line of `Enemy.h` is `#include "Player.h"`: since the file `Player.h` has already been included, the directive is ignored.
- Definition of `Enemy`
- Definition of `Player`
- Definition of the `main` function

As you can see, even with the includes, at the time of the definition of the class `Enemy`, the compiler doesn't know that a class `Player` exists yet. This is the reason why you absolutely need a forward declaration here.

Comment: Thanks, really. Thanks very much!! But, can I ask you why forward declaration is needed, even though I have included the .h in both classes?

Comment: I have a qustion, Is it true that the first letter of the class name should be capitalized ? Or it does not matter anymore? *(in php)* Tnx

Comment: @stack In C++ it is common practice to start class/struct/enum names with a capital letter, but nothing forces you to. As long as your naming conventions are consistent within a project it's fine IMHO.